# Slider not working:Bootstrap template

Tags: jquery, html, css, cordova

I am new to development working on phonegap application,,,Slider is not working and how to have perfect images for slider...

```
        <div id="homepage_content" data-role="content">
    <div class="page-tagline accent-color">
        <img src="assets/img/logo.png" alt="Logo">
    </div>
    <div id="fn_slider" class="owl-carousel owl-active homepage-slider">
            <div class="item">
                <a href="eClinic.html">
                    <img src="assets/img/content-images/1.jpg" alt="eClinic">
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <a href="diseaseLib.html">
                    <img src="assets/img/content-images/2.jpg" alt="DiseaseLibrary">
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <a href="symptomLib.html">
                    <img src="assets/img/content-images/3.jpg" alt="SymptomLibrary">
                </a>
            </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: what slider??? post your code

Comment: can you show us the slider code?